# Can anyone help me with this error im getting? discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

What this is supposed to do is see if a user doesnt have the manage messages perm, then send a message based on what they said, and that works, but its filling my console up with this error.
This is the error that im getting:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\cuzto\Desktop\DiscordBot.-py\cogs\events.py", line 106, in on_message
    if not message.author.permissions_in(message.channel).manage_messages:
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\user.py", line 232, in permissions_in
    return channel.permissions_for(self)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 146, in permissions_for
    base = super().permissions_for(member)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 475, in permissions_for
    roles = member.roles
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'roles'
```

This is the code:

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if not message.author.permissions_in(message.channel).manage_messages:
            if "discord.gg" in message.content.lower():
                await message.delete()
                await message.channel.send(f"temp, <@{message.author.id}>")
```

Will anyone tell me how to fix this? Ive tried a plethora of things and im not sure what else to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is sent in DM not a server.

When DM is sent, `message.author` would be a User object and as you know in DM there are no roles, so its an error.

When a message is sent in a server, `message.author` would be a Member object, User in a Guild becomes Member, as there are roles in a server, Member.roles would be valid.

Make a check that if message does not have guild attribute then return

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, message):
    if not message.guild: return
    if not message.author.permissions_in(message.channel).manage_messages:
        if "discord.gg" in message.content.lower():
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(f"temp, <@{message.author.id}>")
```

Comment: Thanks man, this is what i was looking for, You're a god send

Comment: The error is still persisting 
Add me on discord so we can discuss this easier 
Motzumoto#9773